# how can I show the console of a headless running vbox vm

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

I have a virtualbox headless VM running on CentOS 7. I can show the console of the VM by opening up the virtualbox manager, right clicking the machine and choose "Show". Is there a way to do this (pop up the head of the headless client) without opening up the gui manager, i.e., from the command line? I've tried most likely commands for vboxmanage but get errors or the wrong result.

Comment: Would ssh into the VM give you the same access, or do you require the console for some other reason?

Comment: I require the console. It's a windows-10 instance and I need to access the desktop apps.

Comment: If you wanted to keep it 'headless' you could enable the remote display and access it from any VNC viewer. Or not start in headless mode at all.

Comment: Make that RDP viewer not VNC.

Comment: why is this question in the Close Vote queue? the question being asked is very specific; OP said they'd tried some `vboxmanage` commands and couldn't find the correct one. I don't see how this is a request for a tutorial.

Comment: @strugee: I agree.  Some people seem to be trigger-happy, (over)using that close reason whenever the question uses words like “can you give me an explanation” (in contrast to “can you explain this to me”).  But I don’t see how this question can even remotely be considered a request for learning materials, so I’m voting to leave open.  (Now the case could maybe be made that this question is about a Windows 10 guest in VirtualBox on an unspecified host, so it’s not clearly on topic on U&L, and might be better on [SU]. But it’s here now; let’s see whether anybody can answer it.)

Comment: Clarification: It's not a specific question about a Windows 10 client. Commenter wanted to know why I didn't use ssh and the answer happens to be Window 10 related but could apply to any client where I need to access the gui desktop in the VM and ssh doesn't cut it. I am asking the question in U&L because the host is CentOS and there are other VBox questions here. If there is a more appropriate forum to get an answer, please direct me to it. Superuser has been suggested. How do I transfer the question?

Comment: @ChrisDR : (1) You just partially shot yourself in the foot.  You say that the question “could apply to any client”, reinforcing the ambiguity regarding scope. (2) If your host PC is running CentOS, that (at least potentially) makes the question on-topic at U&L — but you should [edit] your question to mention that, and not hide it here in the comments. (3) I’d suggest that you be patient for another day or two, and see whether anybody posts an answer. If you get no response, click on “flag”, “in need of moderator intervention”, and explain that you want your question moved to [SU].

Comment: @G-man : (1) But that is precisely the point. It is the interaction with virtualbox that I need help with; the client is irrelevant to the question I have. Any client could be running under control of the VM. How do I pop up the head of a headless client from the command line, analogous to clicking "show" in the vbox gui? (2) Will do, although it is also irrelevant. (3) Noted, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So far, no answers. After more research it looks like VirtualBox does not provide this functionality. Best that it seems I can do is to use a remote desktop. For my CentOS, the most convenient app is rdesktop. You need to have the extension pack installed. Then enable remote desktop protocol for the client. Once the VM is running you can then use rdesktop to access the client console. If rdesktop is started immediately after the VM, you do get access to the boot sequence. Thus:

```
$ vboxmanage modifyvm "archive" --vrde on
$ vboxmanage startvm "archive" --type headless ; rdesktop localhost
```